# Is it possible to put an async function as a callable argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, discord.py

I'm coding a music bot for my server, and I need to disconnect (a coroutine) when the queue is exhausted. So I use a try: except block to handle that, however, when using `VoiceClient.play`, is it possible to put an asynchronous function as the `after` parameter?
Just using `after=function` does not work and would raise function was not awaited, but using `after=await function` shows

`TypeError: object function can't be used in 'await' expression`

Is there any way to call an async function from play? How would I disconnect if I cannot call the coroutine?

My code:

```py
def playqueue(error):
    if error: print(error)
    # Next song
    try:
        vcc.play(discord.FFmpegOpusAudio(executable=r"ffmpeg.exe", source=queue[0]), after=playqueue)
    except IndexError:
        # How do I disconnect?

vcc.play(discord.FFmpegOpusAudio(executable=r"ffmpeg.exe", source=tfname), after=playqueue)
```

What I'm trying to do:

```py
async def playqueue(error):
    if error: print(error)
    # Next song
    try:
        vcc.play(discord.FFmpegOpusAudio(executable=r"ffmpeg.exe", source=queue[0]), after=playqueue #Somehow call the async function)
    except IndexError:
        await disconnect # I Have a disconnect function premade

vcc.play(discord.FFmpegOpusAudio(executable=r"ffmpeg.exe", source=tfname), after=playqueue #Somehow call the async function)
```

Comment: I don't understand how `playqueue` is being called, could you send more (all?) of your code

Comment: It’s being called after the audio source has finished/errors out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a callback function that will schedule a coroutine to run on your event loop, wrap it into a `partial` and pass that to the `play` method instead.

```
from functools import partial

def _handle_error(loop, error):
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(playqueue(error), loop) # playqueue should be an async function
    
vcc.play(discord.FFmpegOpusAudio(executable=r"ffmpeg.exe", source=tfname), after=partial(_handle_error, vcc.loop)) # vcc.loop is your event loop instance
```