# Can I use a coroutine function with pyspark forEach?

Tags: pyspark, coroutine, aiohttp

I have a pyspark dataframe that I want to iterate each row and then send each row to an http end point. Is it possible that I use aiohttp post within the forEach function of pyspark dataframe?

```
async def coroutine_http_send(row):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(url, row) as response:
            return response.status_code

async def main(spark, somefile):
    df = spark.read.orc(somefile)
    df.foreach(await coroutine_http_send)

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("app").getOrCreate()
somefile = "path_to_file"

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(spark, somefile))
loop.close()
```

When I run this I get `TypeError: object function can't be used in 'await' expression`

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64758815/is-it-possible-to-put-an-async-function-as-a-callable-argument

Comment: checked that but get error like `_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle select.kqueue objects`